# Edit Magento Configuration settings by file (cant save)

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm having an issue with a magento site where nothing will save, but my error logs are disabled in

> System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings

I can't update them via the admin panel as the issue i'm having will not let me enable them and save the changes, but I can't fix it because I have no error log. Its a vicious cycle!

How can I edit the config settings not using the admin panel? Either my xml file edit or changing the database variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I ended up changing the setting was through the file located at

`homedir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc` and edited the following block in the `config.xml` file

```
<log>
    <active>0</active>
    <file>system.log</file>
    <exception_file>exception.log</exception_file>
</log>
```

and changed `<active>` to 1

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to database and check if entry for developer log is exist or not. 
Query to check is:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE 'dev/log/active';
```

If it results you any record then update value to 1. Else you can add new entry in database with below insert query.

```
insert into `core_config_data` (scope, scope_id, path, value) values('default',0,'dev/log/active', 1);
```

After updating value in database make sure you will flush all magento caches.

Comment: I've fixed it now, will write an answer as to how I changed the setting.